# Delphi 2007 can't start anymore - root element is missing

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Delphi 2007 can't start anymore.
I 've tried re-installed many times but still not working.

[image: root element is missing]

Comment: Thanks for asking the question, the problem just happened to me, I suspect that the EnvOptions.proj was corrupte when I ran out of disk space.  The suggested answer of deleting the .proj file from Application Data\Borland\BDS\5.0 was the solution I needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably encountering the following issue mentioned on the Delphi Wikia page:

[Root element is missing](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Root_element_is_missing)

> If you get the error "root element is missing" when you start the Delphi 2007 IDE, this can be caused by a corrupt file EnvOptions.proj, located in the  `Application Data\Borland\BDS\5.0` subdirectory of your profile. Move this file somewhere else and restart the IDE. If that was the problem, the IDE will regenerate the file and work again.

Comment: have read that page and tried that, but there is no 'EventOptions.proj' anywhere in the folder.

Comment: @DoctorLai Maybe the original author intended to say `EnvOptions.proj` as the file name? Do you have such a file?

Comment: Thanks! You save my life!   It is EnvOptions.proj.  After deleting it, my D2007 is back !   accepting the answer

Comment: @TomBrunberg You are right, I meant to write EnvOptions.prj. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same error message when Windows update force shutdown my system.

My system is Win11, and Alexandria 11.2, while I am testing my project with Android Phone. The IDE showed me "Root element is missing. it cannot process myproject.deployproj".

I tried to save the project as another project, and select the very same name as origin project file, and then recompile it.

Everything comes normal.